# TypeError: histogram weights property or keyword argument not found

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, keyword

I'm trying to produce an histogram making use of the "weights" property or keyword argument. However, although it worked in the past and it appears in the help description, now it fails every now and then (see below). I tried installing and uninstalling anaconda, but it keeps having the same behavior. I also moved a program out from the applications which has its own pythons tasks inside (casa.nrao.edu).

I'm working on macOS 10.13.1 (I wonder if upgrading from 10.12 to 10.13 is the main issue). I'm using python 2.7.14, matplotlib v2.1.1, numpy 1.13.3, ipython 5.4.1 (but the same works in the standard python shell).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

tmp=np.array([1,3,5,2])
wgt=tmp*0+1

np.histogram(tmp,weigths=wgt)
# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-4-43a11ec135ae> in <module>()
# ----> 1 np.histogram(tmp,weigths=wgt)
# TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weigths'

plt.hist(tmp,weigths=wgt)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, hold, data, **kwargs)
# 3023                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
# 3024                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
# -> 3025                       stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
# 1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
# 1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
# -> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
# 6347             if patch:
# 6348                 p = patch[0]
# -> 6349                 p.update(kwargs)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in update(self, props)
# 900         try:
# 901             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v)
# --> 902                    for k, v in props.items()]
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in _update_property(self, k, v)
# 893                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
# 894                 if not callable(func):
# --> 895                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
# ...
# AttributeError: Unknown property weigths

f = plt.figure()
ax2 = f.add_subplot(111)
ax2.hist(tmp,weigths=wgt)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
# 1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
# 1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
# -> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
# 6347             if patch:
# 6348                 p = patch[0]
# -> 6349                 p.update(kwargs)
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in update(self, props)
# 900         try:
# 901             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v)
# --> 902                    for k, v in props.items()]
# ...
# /Users/hugomessias/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in _update_property(self, k, v)
# 893                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
# 894                 if not callable(func):
# --> 895                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
# ...
# Unknown property weigths
```

But every now and then, np.histogram and plt.hist do work, but not ax.plot.

Any guidance would be quite helpful! Thank you in advance!

Comment: It appears that you misspelled "weights" as "weigths"

Comment: You're totally right... I'm embarrassed now. I don't know how I didn't got this. It was one of those days. Thank you for the heads up!